# Loop a map through android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a map to iterate through a database in SQLlite, I want the result into  Edittext    in another activity. The format I am getting is not correct. Here is my code.

```
public  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllS()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Ss;

    Ss = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String query ="SELECT * FROM table where _ID='"+getId()+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("1", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("2", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("3", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("4", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("5", cursor.getString(4));
            Ss.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return Ss;
}
```

The Result I am getting now is

```
[{1=a,2=b,3=c,4=d,5=e} {1=a,2=b,3=c,4=d,5=e} ]
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
Key : 1 Value : a
Key : 2 Value : b
Key : 3 Value : c
Key : 4 Value : d
Key : 5 Value : e
```

Comment: "The format I am getting is not correct." It is good that you posted what is expected. Please also post what is actually being output.

Comment: So you have two records with that ID. Have you declared the `_ID` column as primary key?

Comment: _ID is a primary key. The records could be more since they are user inputs

Comment: Is there any possibility the above result can use  to set it on the edittext       .append("\n"). to make it a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am assuming that your query is like this

```
SELECT value FROM table where _ID='"+getId()+"'"; // only return one column
```

and try this code 
Hashmap is also one list so no need to take ArrayList unless your specific requirement

try this code :)

```
public  HashMap<String, String> getAllS()
{
    HashMap<String, String>   map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String query ="SELECT * FROM table where _ID='"+getId()+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery(query, null);

    int i=0;
    if (cursor != null & cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         int VALUE= cursor.getColumnIndex("value");// saves execution time
         do {
              i++
              map.put(""+i, cursor.getString(VALUE));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Still output in a curly bracket and the select value supposed to  return 5 columns